# Disable Redirect Loop

Tags: php, redirect-loop

Is there any way to disable the Error 310 (Redirect Loop) checking or is there any browser (can be old) that does not have this checking feature?

I need it for a php script i wrote that checks a file with file_get_contents, and it know what file it is by an id i pass to it, then it redirects to the same page with a different id.

Thanks!

Comment: The error should come when you redirect so many times, not just a couple.

Comment: This sounds like the sort of script that should be run in the command line, not a browser.

Comment: how would i run it in a terminal, would i use python?

Comment: You can run PHP in the command line. On a unix box, run `php -a` to enter interactive shell, or `php -f /path/to/file.php` to run a specific file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `header("Location: ...");`, try this:

```
die('<script type="text/javascript">location.href = "'.$new_location.'";</script>');
```

This will circumvent the redirect loop error.

EDIT: Even better:

```
die('Some progress information here...
     <script type="text/javascript">
          setTimeout(function() {location.href = "'.$new_location.'"},50);
     </script>');
```

This way you can display some progress information.

Comment: It just works!!!!!! GREAT! So, to explain, i'm building an app for Facebook, and i need this script for a very crucial thing in my app. When it's ready i'll be sure to mention your help in the credits. thanks!!

Comment: Now the next problem... When i receive a valid object, it is stored in the database and ok, but then it throws a invalid id. ------- 

So it goes like this, i do a $_GET to receive the id, then it adds 1, so $newid = $_GET['id'] + 1, but instead of doing what i imagined it returns a  value like: ------ 

if i put the id=112838412062991 it processes , it is valid and saves the data to my database, but then on the next id, it returns: 1.1283841206299E+14. And it understands that new id as decimal number.

Comment: The numbers are too big, obviously. Stay under 2^32 if you know what's good for you. Either that or use an extension like BC Math.

Comment: Thank you again!! I did: $newid = bcadd($_GET['id'], 1, 0);